# How can i connect an "in pair table" into one string

Tags: roblox

heres what i've come up to but i still cant figure it out

```
for i, v in pairs(game.Players:GetChildren()) do
    print((table.concat(v, "\n")))
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`table.concat` is used to combine an array of objects into a string.
`game.Players:GetChildren()` will give you an array of all of the current Players in a game. While you could pass this array directly into the `table.concat` function, you should probably convert it into an array of the players' names first. That way you know what will actually get printed out.

```
-- create an empty table to store the names
local names = {}

-- get the players' names
local playersArray = game.Players:GetChildren()
for i, player in ipairs(playersArray) do
    table.insert(names, player.Name)
end

-- join all the names together into a string
local playerList = table.concat(names, "\n")
print("Found these players :\n", playerList)
```

And if you ever get stuck and you don't know how to use some Lua functions, you can always look at the Lua Manuals, like this one :

http://lua-users.org/wiki/TableLibraryTutorial